# math latex font in postscript terminal

Tags: gnuplot

I know the epslatex terminal can be used to have fonts in latex style.

But how can I emulate math latex fonts in the postscript terminal?

```
set term postscript size 5,4
set out "test.ps"
pl [][-1.1:1.1] sin(x) t "sin {/Italics x}"
set out
```

[image]

In [math latex](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cdpi%7B150%7D&space;%5Csin&space;x)
 it would look like:

[image]

So it seems I want a serif font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO this is far more trouble than it is worth.  But if you really want to you can download Adobe Type 1 versions of the standard TeX fonts for use in PostScript, specifically for use by the gnuplot postscript terminal.  Here is a demo.

```
#
# Demonstrate use of TeX Computer Modern fonts in gnuplot PostScript terminal
# This demo requires Adobe Type 1 fonts that may not be installed on your system.
# If necessary you can download them from
#    http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/pfb/cmr10.pfb
#    http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/pfb/cmmi10.pfb
#    http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/cm/ps-type1/bakoma/patched-pfb/cmsy10.pfb
# 
set term post eps color fontfile 'cmr10.pfb' fontfile 'cmmi10.pfb' fontfile 'cmsy10.pfb'
set output 'cmfonts.eps'

set title "Use of TeX Computer Modern fonts in gnuplot PostScript terminal"

set label 1 'Times-Roman: {/Times-Roman abcdefghABCDEFGH}'
set label 2 'cmr10: {/cmr10 abcdefghABCDEFGH}'
set label 3 'cmmi10: {/cmmi10 abcdefghABCDEFGH} {/cmmi10 \013\014\015\016\042}'
set label 4 'cmsy10: {/cmmi10 abcdefghABCDEFGH} {/cmsy10 \013\014\015\016\042}'
set label 1 at graph 0.05,0.6 left
set label 2 at graph 0.05,0.5 left
set label 3 at graph 0.05,0.4 left
set label 4 at graph 0.05,0.3 left

set xlabel "{/cmmi10 \013}"
plot [0:2*pi] sin(x) title "{/cmr10 sin({/cmmi10 \013})}"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. `show fontpath` returns also some pathnames and then I found the `*.pfb` files are also in my `/usr/share/fonts/texlive-amsfonts/`.

Answer (score 0):

`Serif` (`Times`) in combination with `Oblique` (`Italic`) also emulates a bit the look of latex math.

```
set term postscript size 5,4
set out "test.ps"
set label 1 'Serif: {/Serif abcdefghABCDEFGH}' at graph 0.05,0.5 left
set label 2 'Serif Oblique: {/SerifOblique abcdefghABCDEFGH}' at graph 0.05,0.4 left
set label 3 'Symbol: {/Symbol abcdefgh}' at graph 0.05,0.3 left
set label 4 'Symbol-Oblique: {/Symbol-Oblique abcdefgh}' at graph 0.05,0.2 left

pl [0:2*pi] sin(x) t "{/Serif sin} {/SerifItalics x}"
set out
```

[image]

This does not fully look as I asked for, but may look even better in documents using Times anyway.

The credit for `Oblique` goes to http://www.gnuplotting.org/postscript-terminal-with-italic-symbols/.